# Plotting a time series in R using ggplot2,

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I'm try to create a time series where, `x = year`, `y = cpue_wt`, grouped by station.  I have 7 stations:  Here is a snapshot of the data, which goes from 1986-2011.  I want one plot, with 7 different lines, each represents one station through time.

```
year  station     cpue_wt
1986    531 3.400346954
1986    537 1.292539282
1986    538 1.097930493
1986    541 1.220753481
1986    550 1.350880331
1986    552 1.168257879
1986    555 2.012733899
1987    531 1.817902609
1987    537 2.024999967
1987    538 1.563596954
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use:

```
SST <- ggplot(Yrsta, aes(group = factor(station), x = year, y = cpue_wt, colour = station)) + geom_line() + scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"))
```

Here is my error:

```
Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
```

I'm assuming my data are not organized correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As `station` values are numeric and you want to set particular color for each line, you should add `as.factor(station)` to `colour=`  to convert numerical values to factor.

```
ggplot(Yrsta, aes(group = factor(station), x = year, y = cpue_wt, colour = as.factor(station))) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00"))
```